# Pulseaudio not working kernel driver broken

Tags: kernel, pulseaudio

Since I plugged in a broken HDD  drive, my pulseaudio won't work. At startup ubuntu stayed checking whether it worked and it took a long time to boot (several start jobs were started).

If I try to start it from console I get the following output.

```
W: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: Your kernel driver is broken: it reports a volume range from 0 to 0 which makes no sense.
W: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: Your kernel driver is broken: it reports a 
volume range from 0 to 0 which makes no sense.
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/root/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authentication key '/root/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/root/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authentication key '/root/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
```

If I try vlc I get the following output:

```
[000055b30db07200] alsa audio output error: cannot open ALSA device "default": No such file or directory
```

I saw many people with the same issues but their solutions somehow didn't  work for me. `pulseaudio -D`  came  in many of them but for me this outputs Daemon startup failed.

Due to these tutorials, I did delete `.pulse`, since it wasn't created at a reboot or startup of pulseaudio, I don't know if it's a problem.

I'm quite new to ubuntu, so don't hesitate to explain whatever it is daemon does and how my HDD affected my kernel.

I'm not  afraid to use the terminal as this is the reason why I switched to ubuntu.

System is Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)

Kernel is 5.3.0-29-generic x86_64

I also changed my home directory to another hard drive, but this shouldn't be a problem because the path would stay the same.

Thanks anyway.

I indeed ran pulseaudio with root access because if I just wrote pulseaudio it said

```
Home directory not accessible: permission denied.
```

If I run systemctl --user restart pulseaudio I get:

```
Job for pulseaudio.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service" and "journalctl --user -xe" for details.
```

If I run systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service I get: run systemctl for  more info

```
Mär 02 16:40:41 tom-X570-AORUS-ELITE systemd[1320]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Mär 02 16:40:41 tom-X570-AORUS-ELITE systemd[1320]: pulseaudio.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Mär 02 16:40:41 tom-X570-AORUS-ELITE systemd[1320]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mär 02 16:40:41 tom-X570-AORUS-ELITE systemd[1320]: Stopped Sound Service.
Mär 02 16:40:41 tom-X570-AORUS-ELITE systemd[1320]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mär 02 16:40:41 tom-X570-AORUS-ELITE systemd[1320]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mär 02 16:40:41 tom-X570-AORUS-ELITE systemd[1320]: Failed to start Sound Service.
```

If you need the output of journalctl do tell me.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `sudo` to run pulseaudio or you are logged in as root. You should not do this.  What commands are you using to start pulseaudio?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that removing and reinstalling pulseaudio fixes this problem for some people. However, the only methods I have seen are quite destructive as many packages depend on pulseaudio. To circumvent the dependency issue, we can purge pulseaudio using `dpkg` instead of `apt`.

**First, run the following commands**:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo dpkg -P --force-all pulseaudio
sudo rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
```

<sub>If you get an error at the last step, ignore the error.</sub>

**Next, reinstall and restart ALSA and pulseaudio**:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

**Finally, you can check the status of pulseaudio with the following command**:

```
systemctl --user status pulseaudio
```

It should return as "loaded" and "active". If not, reboot and check the status again.

Comment: Solution confirmed! This is the 10th one I tried, congrats. Ubuntu 18.04 user on an ASUS  TUF gaming x570-plus motherboard.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer.  Thank you.  I just installed 18.04 onto a fanless mini PC, Intel based. It has no sound.  No output devices of any kind, not even dummy sound, show up in sound settings.  I tried all of the steps you listed and get this:

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor pre
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since 27s ago
  Process: 1347 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no (code=killed, signa
 Main PID: 1347 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
...
pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'sig
Failed to start Sound Service.

Comment: This should really be asked as a separate question. However you can check the logs using `journalctl -b | grep -i pulse`

Comment: @robline Also, I have 18.04 and pulseaudio service is disabled for some reason but it's actually working fine without the service. Try `pulseaudio -k` to simply restart pulseaudio (it should start up on its own).

Comment: @robline Also also, if you're facing the same kernel error as the question, it was supposed to be fixed according to a bug report. If you have the `kernel driver is broken` when you try to run `pulseaudio`, then update ubuntu fully: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`