# Sound devices not detected in Ubuntu 18.04 on ASUS TUF FX 505

Tags: 18.04, sound, asus, speakers

Sound devices are not listed in settings/sound panel, hence not speakers, jack, nor microphone work.

I have tried reinstalling ALSA with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

As explained extensively [on this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218063/1057897), adding the boot parameter

```
snd_hda_intal.dmic_detect=0
```

did it for me.

The way to test this boot parameter temporarily is well described in one of the links in the answer (i.e. [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/1057897)). Making the boot parameter permanent is then quite straightforward, and also thouroughly described there.

Comment: This used to work for me, but then failed. This one ultimately fixed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214154/pulseaudio-not-working-kernel-driver-broken/1214163#1214163